# Unable to set content in SdtElement using WordprocessingDocument

Tags: c#, openxml, placeholder, wordprocessingml

I have a template file in which I have placed two place holders. Both are Plain Text Content Controls. I have following code in which I am setting the values to the Place Holders in the file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{          
    string fileName = "C:\\xxx\\Template.docx";
    byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        memStream.Write(fileContent, 0, (int)fileContent.Length);                
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memStream,true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            var sdtElements = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>();
            foreach (SdtElement sdtElement in sdtElements)
            {
                Tag blockTag = sdtElement.SdtProperties.Descendants<Tag>().ElementAt(0);
                Run nr = new Run();
                Text txt = new Text();
                txt.Text = "RKS";
                nr.Append(txt);
                Lock lckContent = new Lock();
                bool lockControl = true;
                if (lockControl)
                {
                    lckContent.Val = LockingValues.SdtContentLocked;
                }
                else
                {
                    lckContent.Val = LockingValues.Unlocked;
                }
                if (sdtElement is SdtBlock)
                {
                    (((SdtBlock)sdtElement).SdtContentBlock.ElementAt(0)).RemoveAllChildren();
                    (((SdtBlock)sdtElement).SdtContentBlock.ElementAt(0)).AppendChild<Run>(nr);

                    ((SdtBlock)sdtElement).SdtProperties.Append(lckContent);
                }
                if (sdtElement is SdtCell)
                {
                    ((SdtCell)sdtElement).SdtContentCell.ElementAt(0).Descendants<Paragraph>().ElementAt(0).RemoveAllChildren();                        ((SdtCell)sdtElement).SdtContentCell.ElementAt(0).Descendants<Paragraph>().ElementAt(0).AppendChild<Run>(nr);
                    ((SdtCell)sdtElement).SdtProperties.Append(lckContent);
                }
                if (sdtElement is SdtRun)
                {
                    //SdtContentText text = sdtElement.SdtProperties.Elements<SdtContentText>().FirstOrDefault();
                    //((SdtRun)sdtElement).SdtContentRun.ElementAt(0).AppendChild<Text>(emptyTxt);
                    ((SdtRun)sdtElement).SdtContentRun.ElementAt(0).RemoveAllChildren();
                    ((SdtRun)sdtElement).SdtContentRun.ElementAt(0).AppendChild<Run>(nr);
                    ((SdtRun)sdtElement).SdtProperties.Append(lckContent);
                }
            }
            wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();                    
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs successfully but the changes are not reflected in the file.

What am I missing?

Comment: I can see the value i.e, RKS is set in `<w:sdtContent>` tag but I can't come to know why it is not showing in the actual file?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a `WordprocessingDocument` from a memory stream, so there is no way for the class to know which file to write to. It writes all changes to the memory stream, not the file.

You can create a `WordprocessingDocument` directly from a file by calling `WordprocessingDocument.Open` method and specifying the name of your file (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument.aspx) and then the changes should be reflected in the file.

If you need to load the document into a buffer for some reason, then you need to copy the data from the buffer back to the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

After making some experiments, I could not understand how it worked but it is fine for me. I just save the file with other name.

After the code line: `wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();` I added

`File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\xxx\\Sample.docx", memStream.ToArray());`